# How to extract data <d> in svg through javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I wrote an icon component through reactjs to parse the svg files. I use storybook to show my icon component. Now I need help for writing a command line to parse the svg file to the component. I need to script the  element  in  in a svg file and I have no idea how to achieve it.

I am planning to write it in javascript. And here is one example of my svg files.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" p-id="3378" width="200" height="200">
  <path d="..." p-id="3379"></path>
</svg>
```

May anyone gives me some ideas on how to achieve it. I am bad at extracting data from a file.

Comment: Hey! Welcome to Stack Overflow. We tend not to write code for you around here, rather, we help you sort problems when you run into them. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @frobinsonj I haven't tried anything yet because I don't know where to start. But I had thought to do something like document.getElementById and getAttribute but the svg files I downloaded online don't have an id attribute. And I cannot change the svg files itself because my company asks me to batch processing the svg files on www.iconfont.us.

Comment: @DonghuaZhang If you download the svg files you can edit them in your favorite text editor or svg-aware graphics design software ( eg. Inkscaoe ) - just remember that SVG is an xml dialect and therefore svgs are human-readable (in porinciple ... ;)). If you choose not to edit the SVG source you can access the embedded svg with JS: 1. in your html; `... <object type="image/svg+xml" data="https://..." width="480" height="240"></object>`, 2. in your JS: `let e_svg = document.querySelector("object").contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];`.You then have a handle on the svg root element ...

Comment: ... Note that html and svg have to reside on the same server due to the browser's same-origin policy, so you cannot use this method when linking directly to the iconfont server. SVG provides a DOM API similar to the html DOM which will allow you to manipulate the document (eg. adding/deleting [SVG] elements, setting/deleting/modifying attributes). More Information is available [from here](http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/tutorials/svg/interactive/javascript/). For a genuine answer please be more specific on what you want to achieve. People here will help you but they will not do your job ;)

Answer (score 1):

For the specific question from the title, use the following JS code:

```
document.querySelector("object")
    .contentDocument.querySelectorAll("path[path-id='3379']")[0].getAttribute("d")
```

The SVG should be referenced using the `object` element (replace `width`/`height` attribute content with proper values):

```
<object
    type="image/svg+xml"
    data="./logo.svg"
    width="480"
    height="240"
></object>
```

It is assumed that there is a single `object` element in your html. Otherwise tag them with an `id` attribute and use `#<the_id_goes_here>` in the first selector:

```
document.querySelector("#<the_id_goes_here>")
    .contentDocument.querySelectorAll("path[path-id='3379']")[0].getAttribute("d")
```